# Sharepoint - SAML Authentication

Tags: 2010, authentication, claims-based-auth, claims, claim-provider

I have a Sharepoint web application running on SAML security (based on user e-mail). I have a problem with one user that is not managing to log-in. Basically the IT admin, have done a mistake and have entered a typo in the user's email address (even if you look for the email in outlook, it was not showing correctly). They have now fixed this. Now, if you search for the contact in outlook it is correct.

However, if the user tries to log-in in Sharepoint, it is showing an anauthorized message. This message also shows a "you are logg-in as email" message. However, the email here is still with the typo.

I have already been going back and forth with the admin team to check it from their end but they are saying it is ok. I would like to know how best to investigate this issue and what can I do to get more information.

Comment: Try to remove the user from all permissions and add him back in.

Comment: do you use the ad Sync process? When yes, look if it was running. Maybe the actual data is not synchronized.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try to remove user from all SharePoint groups and add him back. No, I am not using the user profile synchronization.

Comment: Tried to remove the user from all permissions and added him again but user still received access denied error